How can Afghan origin mother with Canadian citizenship legally immigrate to UK to live with daughter with British citizenship?
I've searched various websites, but the situation rarely gives results as it is so specific. My friend is the British citizen and her elderly mother wants to come and live with her permanently. At the moment, mum can only visit for 6 months maximum and doesn't get healthcare or any other access to state support. Mum is diabetic and her medicine may even run out before the 6 months is over. Any ideas very welcome.

What type of visa options are available to them?
Would they need a solicitor to make an application, or can it be done by layperson?


Which websites have you searched? The official UK gov site is the place to start for information about family visa options.

Not really relevant to the question, but your friend's mother can get 6 months of medicine prescribed by her doctor in Canada.

Have now started searching through gov websites. There's some legal jargon which I don't understand but I will try and find out for them. Thanks also about the tip of getting medicine in advance. She has 3 months worth already, but wanted to visit a doctor's office related to her diabetes and they wouldn't let her access healthcare due to her temporary visa status.

@LJ Why would she expect to be able to access routine NHS healthcare as a visitor to the UK? Having appropriate medical insurance is a must for any destination.

They are originally from Afghanistan and she doesn't read or write. I'm not sure if she knows what health insurance is, or how it works. I will check with her daughter.

Q1
Inputting basic details (citizenship, purpose of travel to the UK, immigration status of the family member in the UK) into this tool results in You must usually apply for a family visa.
The only category under which an application might be possible is Apply as an adult coming to be cared for by a relative.
To apply, it is necessary to prove a need for long-term care to do everyday personal and household tasks because of illness, disability or age, and that the care needed is not available or affordable in the country where the applicant lives. The relative in the UK must prove they can accommodate and care for the applicant and must have enough money to support them without relying on public funds (i.e. state benefits).
Q2 Applications are done online. A lay person should be able to complete it and compile the supporting paperwork, however advice from an immigration lawyer might be a good idea.
